# Input path limit for Android ndk source file

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there a known limit on the path for the Android ndk input files?  I've run into an issue where the input path is over 155 characters the android g++ command fails to find the file.

The local path back down to my base directory is quite deep, in a few cases I have a full path back to a source file in the jni project making the path a bit long, though 155 doesn't seem like a very high limit.

`LOCAL_PATH              := $(call my-dir)/../../../../../../../../../..`

Here is an example of a failure, at 155 characters:

```
/cygdrive/c/java/Android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -c  jni/VECodecG723/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/./././VECodecG723/VECodecG723.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: error: jni/VECodecG723/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/./././VECodecG723/VECodecG723.cpp: No such file or directory
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
```

And a success case, at 153 characters:

```
/cygdrive/c/java/Android/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -c  jni/VECodecG723/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/././VECodecG723/VECodecG723.cpp
jni/VECodecG723/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/../gen/././VECodecG723/VECodecG723.cpp:26:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
```

The repeating ../gen is just for this sample, the actual path contains 10 ../ and then the full path back to the file.

I've tried the paths with the regular g++ compiler and it does not fail because of the path length.  I have also tried this in a Windows command shell with the android g++ and it has the same issue.

Is there anything I can do short of renaming my folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another look at this and figured it out.  I was running into the max path length for Windows, 260 characters or so.  When I added the base path forming an absolute path to the source file the breaking point was around the windows max.  No good way around  this other than to build on Linux or a Mac.